# access master page hidden field value in child page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having hidden element in Master page. I am setting its value in master page code behind. I want to access that value in one of its child page.

```
public partial class MasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        hdnSessionContext.Value = "Some Value";
    }
}
```

.Master Page

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdnSessionContext" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" />

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContainer" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

What i tried (SomeChildPage.aspx.cs)

```
HtmlInputHidden hdnFieldValue = (HtmlInputHidden)Page.Master.FindControl("hdnSessionContext");
```

And

```
HiddenField hdnFieldValue = (HiddenField)Page.Master.FindControl("hdnSessionContext");
```

But both having Value as `''`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would pass the value into the child control instead. You don't want to call master page from child control because that would tightly  couple the two.

Comment: One way is to create a property on child control and assign from the mater page.

Comment: Another way is using events.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access HiddenField value before it's being set, The page load of your child page fires before page load event of Master page and thats why you are not getting any value.

if value is to be set is known then try setting it in .aspx page, in that case you will be able to get value in child page.